# Jquery Datepicker disappears on switching input fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

I am using jquery datepicker in my application. It starts behaving abnormally if I directly switch from one input field to another. If I close it by clicking "done" button on datepicker or click elsewhere before focusing in on the next input field it works well.

**Code to initialize datepicker**

```
$(".date").datetimepicker({
  dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'
  timeFormat: 'h:mm tt'
  controlType: 'select'
  stepMinute: 15
  hour: 9
  maxDate: new Date()
  hourMin: 6
  hourMax:21
  minuteMax:61
});
```

**Jquery Version**

- Jquery: jquery-2.1.1

**Jquery UI Version**

- jquery-ui-1.10.3.js
- jquery-ui-1.10.2.css

**Bootstrap Version**

- Bootstrap v3.3.6

I have actually tried by changing the Jquery UI versions but it didn't work.

**Jquery UI verions I tried**

- jquery-ui-1.10.4
- jquery-ui-1.11.4
- jquery-ui-1.12.1

Morever, I tried to to recreate this issue on JSFiddle but it works fine there.

**Demo of the issue**

[image]

Comment: Take a look into the console for errors. Maybe there is a blur event missing. Show us some of the code.

Comment: show your code....

Comment: Which browser are you using and does this occur in all browsers you test with?

Comment: I am checking on Chrome and Firefox latest versions.

Comment: Code snippet added, please check